# How to append the Server ip-address along with the existing 'Web Page Title'

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

In our application, we use 3DNS name and when user hits the 3DNS name, it will route to the different servers(load balancing)

Assume : if user hits Harmony.com(3dns)
        Depending on load it will hit server1(managedserver - ip 10.0.0.1) or server2(managedserver 10.0.0.2)         or server3(managedserver 10.0.0.3) or server4(managedserver 10.0.0.4)

Now when user reports a bug(by sending screen shot), we will not be knowing
log is written in which server. so we need to scan all the logs of server1,server2,server3,server 4.

In-order to overcome this issue, we have decided, to append (ipaddress or nickname A/B/C/D) along with the existing page title

Harmony Welcome Page - A(page title if it hits server1)
Harmony Welcome Page - B(page title if it hits server2)
Harmony Welcome Page - C(page title if it hits server3)
Harmony Welcome Page - D(page title if it hits server4)

So if user sends the screen shot from the web-page title in the screen shot, we will now if it is server 1 or server 2 etc, which help us in locating the right log.

Different pages in our application will have different titles.

for simplicity lets append (Title - ipaddress) instead of (Title - A/B/C/D), Harmony Welcome Page - ipaddress.

The below code, returns me the ipaddress.

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

Now my requirement is , i want to append this ipaddress along with the existing Title.

so if existing title is 'Main page', now with change it should be 'Main page - 10.0.0.2'

I cannot go and modify all the jsp's.

1.How to do this with servlet filter? how to get the existing title?

2.Any better approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Do your pages use a base template like facelets, tiles, or decorators?  That's the best way I can think of.

Comment: yes, some modules use tiles but not all.In many jsp pages, we are using a custom header[WFHeader.jsp to have common header style].Most of them are coded with struts framework and jsp view, without tiles.

Comment: I think the best way is , embed the ipaddress in to the WFHeader.jsp, [Since WFHeader is a header in most pages, somewhere embed in the header bar of our web application], than the page title. In Tiles module, come with a different approach.